# Explaination for and derivation of the formula to calculate unknown temperature

Tags: temperature

In my textbook it is mentioned that

> "a thermometer is constructed using some physical property (say $X$) of a substance which changes with temperature in a known manner. For example in a mercury thermometer, the length of mercuric thread is taken as the thermometric property. The value of property $X$ is determined at two reference temperatures, generally the ice-point ($X_i$) and steam-point ($X_s$). the difference between is divided into some equal parts, say $n$ parts. The value of property $X$ is then determined at unknown temperature ($X_t$) and the unknown temperature $t$ is determined by $$t=\frac{X_t-X_i}{X_s-X_i} n.$$

I am unable to understand this so can someone please explain and derive this formula.

Comment: please use mtahjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

You can understand where this formula comes by drawing
the graph for $t$ (temperature) versus $X_t$ (length of mercury thread).

You want a linear relation between $X_t$ and $t$.
And you know two special points of the graph
(the ice-point and the steam-point).
$$\begin{array}{r|r|r}
X_t & t & \\
\hline
X_i & 0 & \text{ice-point} \\
X_s & n & \text{steam-pont}
\end{array}$$

This is enough information to draw the graph:

[image]

The equation for this graph is
$$t=\frac{X_t-X_i}{X_s-X_i} n.$$
This is obviously a linear relation between $X_t$ and $t$,
as required. Futhermore,
you need to verify the correctness of this formula by inserting
the two special values of $X_t$ and calculating the corresponding values of $t$.

- For $X_t=X_i$ you get $t=0$,
- for $X_t=X_s$ you get $t=n$.

---

The two special points can be chosen arbitrarily.
Examples are

- [Celsius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius) scale: $0=$ ice-point of water, $100=$ steam-point of water
- [Fahrenheit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit) scale: $0=$ ice-point of a certain water-salt mixture,
  $96=$ human body temperature)
- [Réaumur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9aumur_scale) scale: $0=$ ice-point of water, $80=$ steam-point of water)

Comment: Thank you Thomas it was really helpful.

Comment: I have a question, was considering the two special points completely arbitrary?

Comment: @AyushSharma Yes, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

$X$ in can in this case indicate where it is between the 2 known endpoints. To associate temperature value with $X$ value, linear interpolation is used. So for example if $X$ is at 2/3 between $X_i$ and $X_s$, you want the temperature $t$ also be at 2/3 between $t_i$ and $t_s$.